# Do something when a session ends

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

basically i just need to do something when a session ends in javascript.

I have already tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = function ()
```

**but is there a way to do it with cookies or something.**
i have to do this is javascript because it is to be used for other sites not just mine so i cant do anything server side.

Comment: Sessions end on the server side; closing a window doesn't automatically end a session.

Comment: What do you mean by "when a session ends"?  What was wrong with `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: Regularily reload the site/ping the server?

Comment: use a session cookie for example when the window is closed and all session cookies are removed

Comment: @KyleBC What if there are other windows or tabs loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want if all browser tabs of your site are closed?

```
var state=false;
setInterval(function(){
 state=false;
 window.postMessage("ami","*");
 setTimeout(function(){
 try{
 if(state==false){
 window.lonely();
 }
 }catch(e){}
},2000);
},5000);
window.addEventListener("message",function(e){
  if(e.data=="ami"){
  window.postMessage("no!","*");
  }else if(e.data=="no!"){
    state=true
  }});
```

Use like this:

```
window.lonely=function(){
  alert("im alone :(");
 };
```

Comment: You'd reload the window from underneath the user? And if the window is gone, that `setTimeout` would never occur.

Comment: @Dave: nothing else will occur (except a complicated construct of service workers...)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment "use a session cookie for example when the window is closed and all session cookies are removed", have you considered using `window.sessionStorage`?

From it's page on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, **data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends**. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

*(my emphasis added)*

From what it sounds like you are trying to do, this may be exactly what you need.

***NOTE: Do NOT use this for storing any authentication or other sensitive data.***

Comment: no i have not considered it and how would i use this so at the time where the session end i could send data to an api

Comment: Ah, okay, yeah, that would not work.  I misunderstood based on your comment what it is that you are trying to do.  To my knowledge, there is no way to trigger an action when `sessonStorage` is cleared.